# Are there any tools to do Migrations (a la Ruby) on Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL)?

Tags: sql-server, migration

Are there any tools, or 'best practices' for creating Migrations on MSSQL? I have a Dev & Production database, and the Dev one often has new SPROCs created, and occasionally the structure is added to. I'd like to be able to write a set of scripts during each iteration which will update the Dev server, then execute all the scripts at release time to update Production. In ruby I can do this with migrations - is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few:

- [Rails Migrations running on SQL Server](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoConnectToMicrosoftSQLServer)
- [RikMigrations](http://www.rikware.com/RikMigrations.html)
- [Tarantino](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/)
- [Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/)
- [Machine Migrations](http://blog.eleutian.com/2008/04/25/AFirstLookAtMachineMigrations.aspx)
- [Subsonic Migrations](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/10/03/subsonic-migrate-me/)
- [dbDeploy.NET](http://dbdeploy.com/2007/09/25/dbdeploynet-v10-officially-released/)
- [Fluent Migrator](http://wiki.github.com/enkari/fluentmigrator)

[Source](http://flux88.com/blog/net-database-migration-tool-roundup/)

For what it's worth, my favourite of these is Fluent Migrator.

Comment: I'm sure I can get one of those working :-) Cheers! Don't suppose anyone knows of any Java-based ones? (I know, Java + MSSQL - wasn't my choice..)

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were on .NET

Comment: That's ok - most people would.. Not to worry, our backend stuff doesn't have to be Java, so I'm sure it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here at Red Gate we've now got a migrations solution that uses SQL Compare and SQL Source Control.

http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=14107

It's currently an early access build, due out by the end of the year, so we're keen to get as much feedback as possible.